# How do I specify three different types of response in the Go application using usecase.Interactor

Tags: go, openapi

I am writing a Go web service using `usecase.Interactor` to automatically generate the documentation in the OpenAPI 3 standard. How to properly issue a `usecase.NewInteractor` so that the output can be of different types?

For example, my OpenAPI schema describes three different types of responses:

```json
...
"/phonenumber/get/" : {
  "post" : {
    "operationId" : "getInfo",
    "requestBody" : {
      "required" : true,
      "content" : {
        "application/json" : {
          "schema" : {
            "$ref" : "#/components/schemas/RequestInfo"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "responses" : {
      "200" : {
        "content" : {
          "application/json" : {
            "schema" : {
              "oneOf" : [ {
                "$ref" : "#/components/schemas/ResponsePhoneExist"
              }, {
                "$ref" : "#/components/schemas/ResponsePhoneNoExist"
              }, {
                "$ref" : "#/components/schemas/ResponsePhoneInArchive"
              } ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
...
```

`ResponsePhoneExist`, `ResponsePhoneNoExist` and `ResponsePhoneInArchive` are different types in my Go app:

```golang
type ResponsePhoneExist struct {
  Result string `json:"result,omitempty" required:"true" enum:"ok" example:"ok"`
  Info string `json:"info,omitempty" required:"true" enum:"exist" example:"exist"`
  Phonenumber string `json:"phonenumber,omitempty" required:"true" minLength:"11" maxLength:"11" example:"79146764408"`
  Сount int `json:"count,omitempty" required:"true" minimum:"0" maximum:"3" example:"1"`
  Activated string `json:"activated,omitempty" required:"true" example:"27.11.2022"`
}

type ResponsePhoneNoExist struct {
  Result string `json:"result,omitempty" required:"true" enum:"ok" example:"ok"`
  Info string `json:"info,omitempty" required:"true" enum:"no exist" example:"no exist"`
  Phonenumber string `json:"phonenumber,omitempty" required:"true" minLength:"11" maxLength:"11" example:"79146764408"`
}

type ResponsePhoneInArchive struct {
  Result string `json:"result,omitempty" required:"true" enum:"ok" example:"ok"`
  Info string `json:"info,omitempty" required:"true" enum:"archive" example:"archive"`
  Phonenumber string `json:"phonenumber,omitempty" required:"true" minLength:"11" maxLength:"11" example:"79146764408"`
}
```

Then I define the web service in the `main()` function:

```golang
func main() {
  service := web.DefaultService()
  ...
  service.Docs("/docs", v4emb.New)
  service.Post("/phonenumber/get", getPhoneInfo())
  err := http.ListenAndServe(":3400", service)
  ...
}

func getPhoneInfo() usecase.Interactor {
  u := usecase.NewInteractor(func(ctx context.Context, request RequestInfo, response ???) error {
    *response, err = getInfoIn1C(request.PhoneNumber)
    if err != nil {
      return status.Wrap(errors.New(err.Error()), status.Internal)
    }
    return nil
  })
  u.SetName("getInfo")
  u.SetExpectedErrors(status.Unauthenticated, status.InvalidArgument, status.Internal)
  return u
}

func getInfoIn1C(tel string) (???, error) {
  var out ???
  var err error
  ...
  return out, err
}
```

What type instead of `???` should I specify so that the automatically generated OpenAPI documentation satisfies the fragment given above?

I tried adding this interface:

```golang
type ResponsePhone interface {
  ResponsePhoneExist | ResponsePhoneNoExist | ResponsePhoneInArchive
}
```

But Go returns an error:

> cannot use type ResponsePhone outside a type constraint: interface contains type constraints

I tried modifying the interface:

```golang
type ResponsePhoneConstraint interface {
  ResponsePhoneExist | ResponsePhoneNoExist | ResponsePhoneInArchive
}

type ResponsePhone[T ResponsePhoneConstraint] struct {
  Response T
}
```

Now Go return this error:

> cannot use generic type ResponsePhone[T ResponsePhoneConstraint] without instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

you should use Class Inherit like:

```
type ResponsePhoneNoExist struct {
    Result      string `json:"result,omitempty" required:"true" enum:"ok" example:"ok"`
    Info        string `json:"info,omitempty" required:"true" enum:"exist" example:"exist"`
    Phonenumber string `json:"phonenumber,omitempty" required:"true" minLength:"11" maxLength:"11" example:"79146764408"`
}

type ResponsePhoneExist struct {
    ResponsePhoneNoExist
    Сount     int    `json:"count,omitempty" required:"true" minimum:"0" maximum:"3" example:"1"`
    Activated string `json:"activated,omitempty" required:"true" example:"27.11.2022"`
}

type ResponsePhoneInArchive struct {
    ResponsePhoneNoExist
}
```

1. you can use interface{}, follow is a example:

```
func getInfoIn1C(tel string) (interface{}, error) {
    out := ResponsePhoneExist{}
    out.Phonenumber = tel
    return &out, nil
}

func getPhoneInfo() {
    response, _ := getInfoIn1C("112233")
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", response)

}
```

2. you can use `Generics`,follow is a example:

```
func getPhoneInfo() {
    response, _ := getInfoIn1C("112233")
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", response)

}

func getInfoIn1C(tel string) (any, error) {
    out := ResponsePhoneExist{}
    out.Phonenumber = tel
    return any(out), nil
}
```

ps: `type any = interface{}` 1 is same 2

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about including a type in a type. But with this approach, I lose the correct description of the returned values. In the ResponsePhoneExist structure, the Info value can only be "exist". And in the ResponsePhoneNoExist structure, the Info value can only be "no exist". In ResponsePhoneInArchive Info, there can only be an "archive".

Comment: it doesn't matter  you say above, use `interface{}` or `any`

Comment: I got an answer that suits me on github: [link](https://github.com/swaggest/rest/discussions/136)